# Changing SVn Repository

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I had a system loss due to a hard drive crash.
I could not restore that machine so I built another one with a different name and restored the repository from a backup.

I have outstanding changes checked out and use Tortoise SVN as my client.
I cannot do any commits of the changes because the configuration is pointing to the old repository.

Is there a simple way to change the configuration so that the client points to the new repository?

Answer (score 2):

Found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16948970/2115477):

Use the [`svn relocate`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html) command.
It takes either `FROM-PREFIX TO-PREFIX [PATH...]` or `TO-URL` as arguments.

See
`svn help relocate`
for more information.